# Simple URL rewrite, not redirect, with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm pretty inexperienced with .htaccess so please bear with me.

I have a domain - "http://www.exampletest.com"

which redirects to a folder at a different domain where I have hosting i.e:

"http://www.differenturl.com/exampletest"

Is there an easy mod_rewrite rule where I could have anything at "http://www.differenturl.com/exampletest" show up as "http://www.exampletest.com?"  An example would be:

"http://www.differenturl.com/exampletest/user.php" -> "http://www.exampletest.com/user.php"

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I assume this easy so sorry to ask such a basic question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, following code might do:

```
RewriteRule exampletest/(.*)$ http://www.exampletest.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please note that you add this line in the .htaccess file placed on differenturl.com server.

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You say "rewrite, not redirect", so no, there isn't a simple way to do this. The only way to do what you ask would be to have a "reverse proxy" running on www.exampletest.com that fetches content from "www.differenturl.com/exampletest/". That isn't something you can do with  mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.  I tried what you suggested Ali and it doesn't seem to be working.